# RSA : Is there a way to compute phi(n) or N itself if we only know e, d and a ciphertext?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, factoring

I am trying to solve a problem where private key exponent d, ciphertext c, and public key exponent e (65537) are known.
How can I calculate φ(n) or n itself?

An extended version of the problem would be :
*If we can get many d and ciphers for the same plaintext, where e is always 65537, is there a way to decrypt the cipher?*

Comment: Couple of hints - what is the definition of $e$ and $d$? How do they relate to $\phi(N)$?

Comment: Hints given are more than enough to solve this *without* number theory.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144678/discussion-on-question-by-bd55-rsa-is-there-a-way-to-compute-phin-or-n-itsel); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.