# RSA: decipher c when everything except N is known

Tags: rsa

Is it possible to solve this:

If you have the following information about an RSA ecrypted plaintext $m$:

$e = 65537$
$d$, $c$ some very large numbers 
$p$ and $q$ are both random 128-bit long prime numbers 
$m$ is a string build with 16 random characters of both ascii letters and digits

If $N$ would be known $m \equiv c^d \mod N$ could be computed, however I have no clue how I would get either $m$ or $N$.

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ known? I'm implicitly assuming yes.

Comment: @DannyNiu No, I don't know what their value is. The only information about them is that they are 128-bit long prime numbers. But $c$ and $d$ are know. I can provide you with numbers if that may be of help.

Comment: There seems to be a [duplicate](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/105702/36960) *homework* questions. The fellows gave some hint on it.